# Up to what temperature, can titanium be safely used?

Tags: structural-engineering, materials, temperature

I was thinking about the realization of a pottery oven, and I wondered which material I could to make the inner walls. Most often the inner walls seem to be made of some kind of hard mineral wool. I also had the idea to make them in fire clay, but then I wondered if titanium would hold such temperatures (up to 1200-1300°C).

It seems mechanically OK, but I feared there might be a possible problem of oxidization, if not even a risk of fire. At what temperature might such kind of problems appear with titanium ?

Comment: pottery oven need not be a thermally conductive copper pot.  Depend on the air inside to carry heat.  depend on the walls to handle pressure and insulate (mineral wool rather than a mineral slab!).  titanium is pretty weak once you get it hot- nickel superalloys fare much better with heat, but even those can't compare to ceramics in compression.

Comment: Bad idea, stay with ceramics. If you must use metal ,304, 309,310 then Inconels would be the order of increasing temperature resistance. Titanium is subject to high temperature damage by salt, hydrogen , oxygen. nitrogen, etc.

Comment: @Abel, I don't understand your answer: Why are you talking about thermally conductive copper pot? Titanium is not very good for thermal conductivity and the only reason I thought about doing that, was to have a light and clean protective surface between the inside and the isolation. (However the answers here convinced me not to do it ;-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The titanium melting temperature is close to 1670 deg C.
However most titanium alloys have a [maximum service temperature of 600  deg C](https://www.amt-advanced-materials-technology.com/materials/titanium-high-temperature/).

In any case, purchasing and manufacturing cost would be prohibitive compared to the alternatives that you've mentioned.